# Insert formula with Variable VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to insert a formula in the Column C of Sheet2. The row number however depends on the value of pasterow. The range in the formula should be G[lastrow]:NS[lastrow] with lastrow pertaining to the last row of Sheet1.

Here is my code:

```
Sub try()

With Sheets("Sheet2")

pasterow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & pasterow).formula = _
    "=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G & lastRow & :NS & lastRow & , ""VL"" )"

End With
End With

End Sub
```

I'll really appreciate if someone could point out what's wrong with my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The VBA variables are inside your formula string.  Compare:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & pasterow).formula = "=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G" & lastrow & ":NS" & lastrow & ", ""VL"" )"
```

Comment: It still wasn't fixed. It says "Application-defined or Object-defined error". I updated my post and included the entire code.

Comment: What formula you want to put (Excel form) ?

Comment: If that's your entire code still, you didn't make my suggested change to remove the variables from the string.  Making that change, I ended up with `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G21:NS21, "VL" )` at the end of Column C on Sheet2; without it, I get the application error you described.

Comment: Yep.  Made two sheets of dummy data (ten columns, twenty rows) and pasted your code in a new module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & pasterow).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C[4]:C[380],""VL"")"
```

May be this is what your expecting to achieve!

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & pasterow).Value = "=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G" & lastRow & ":NS" & lastRow & ", ""VL"" )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & pasterow).formula = _  
"=COUNTIF(Sheet1!R" & lastrow & "C7:R" & lastrow & "C383,""VL"")"
```